# I want to remove icon from windows MDI child form

Tags: c#, mdi

There is same problem related with icon. I am satisfy with your answer that seticon property to false. But my form is child of MDI form, then this problem is remain same that icon is not remove.
Can you help me.

Comment: no idea which icon you are refering too; please change your question into something which we can answer too.

Comment: There is a property ICON in windows form that   by default on the left side of top of the window from. 
but if i will false the property "show icon", it will hide from form. but the form is child of MDI form. so it will display again.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is a "feature" of the Windows MDI implementation.  Design guides require the child form to have an icon so it is easy for the user to see what child was maximized and where to click to activate the system menu.  The Windows Forms designer should have disabled the "ShowIcon" property and force it True but it can't because it doesn't know yet that the form will become an MDI child.

You'll have to work around it.  One possibility is using a 1x1 icon that's transparent so it won't be visible when the child form is maximized.  It is however not an ideal fix, the form's caption text will be shifted to the right.  The path of least resistance is to simply create an icon for the form.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c7c1bea-7f37-4786-acb4-5685f827f8f2/remove-child-forms-icon-from-mdi-menustrip?forum=winforms) you can make such item invisible:

```
private void MenuStrip_ItemAdded(object sender, ToolStripItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.Text == "")
    {
        e.Item.Visible = false;
    }
}
```