# Delete icon from MDI container form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

[image]

I have a parent form and some child forms. Each of the child form has an icon at the top and left of the form. I would like to discard those icons but when I click on the icon property, I can only browse another icon and not delete the existing one. For that reason I set the showIcon property in each child form to false and the icons are not visible any more on the forms. So far so good.

My problem is that when a child form is open and maximized, the icon is shown. I want to make it go away and unfortunately I didn't find a way to do this. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

EDIT: I added a screenshot of the form, the unwanted icon is shown above menu strip. I want it to go away. When child form is NOT maximized, the icon disappears.

Comment: Sorry cant understand the problem. Can you add screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Can you post the code that's not functioning

Comment: Thank you both for your responce. @Sandeep G B: There is no problematic code, I just want the icon above menu strip to go away. I didn't write any extra code.

Comment: Yes the main form is MDI container.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the real problem is that the menu should be immediately below the caption bar. Who owns the menu? Is it owned by the child form? MDI child menus are meant to merge with the MDI form's menu.

Comment: it doesn't depend child form has menustrip or not. it just showing icon when child form maximized. And SO i think want that child form icon won't displayed when form is maximized.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Until now the menu strip was not owned by anyone. I made the menu strip to be owned by parent form but no luck. The only difference is that the icon is shown at the left of (before) the menu strip and not above it.

Comment: "The icon is shown at the left of (before) the menu strip and not above it." That is how an MDI app is meant to be.

Comment: @Reniuz: Icon is shown ONLY when child form is maximized.

Comment: The MainMenuStrip property of all child forms is none. The MenuStrip property of the parent form is MenuStrip1 (my menu Strip). Is there any solution?

Comment: Could you correct your question title please. It confused me. The issue is not the menu strip. The icon doesn't show in the menu strip.

Comment: @alexxx I understood the problem. You just wrote that you want to remove icon from menustrip, but actually you want to remove child forms icon.

Comment: @Reniuz: Exactly!!! Is there a way?

Comment: @David Heffernan: My problem is that I want this icon to be gone. I think that the title is OK.

Comment: Well, the title is complete nonsense because you can clearly see that the menu strip is beneath the row with the icon. Delete the menu strip and the icon is still there. Such details matter (to me).

Comment: @David Heffernan. You are right, I tried your suggestion. I deleted the menu strip and the icon is still there (only when child form is maximized). The title came out of my believe that menu strip was responsible, sorry about that. But where does this problem lie? If I understand that, I will change the title immediately. EDIT: I changed the title, I think it is much more reprensetative now.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872740/i-want-to-remove-icon-from-windows-mdi-child-form/2873918#2873918) is workaround suggested by Hans Passant, it might help.

Comment: @alexxx What Hans said, is what I said above. That's how an MDI app is meant to be.

Comment: @Reniuz: Thank you for the refernence, I think this is a "dirty" solution to work with if no other solution possible. But is this the case? There is no other solution?

Comment: @alexxx yes its dirty, but it's the only solution I found.

Comment: @Reniuz: Of course, and thank you very much about it. If no other solution will be found, I will follow this one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to create a custom form border.
Please check http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/articles/CustomBorderForms3.aspx

Comment: Hi ControlPower!  I don't understand. Is it so complicated to make an icon go away that I have to create custom form border? There must be a simpler solution than that.